# Facing problem in passing param in DB2 query

Tags: java, database, spring-boot, db2

Query is to select new cases reports from database where input parameters are Id, fromdate and todate.

I have written a `MapSqlParameterSource` class which is not working so as an alternative how can I directly pass these params in queryforlist without changing query.

```
MapSqlParameterSource source = new MapSqlParameterSource();
source.addValue(Constants.FROMDATE.getValue(), CommonUtils.formatDateddmmyyyy("01-01-2020", "yyyy-MM-dd"),Types.CHAR);
source.addValue(Constants.TODATE.getValue(), CommonUtils.formatDateddmmyyyy("12-12-2021", "yyyy-MM-dd"),Types.CHAR);
source.addValue("issuerid", "50191150159",Types.CHAR);
```

what could be the alternative way of passing values?

Answer (score 0):

You can create a `Map<String, T>` and add your parameters to it first, then pass the Map into the constructor.

```
Map<String, (whatever the value type would be)> parameters = new HashMap<>();
parameters.add(Constants.FROMDATE.getValue(), CommonUtils.formatDateddmmyyyy("01-01-2020", "yyyy-MM-dd"));
parameters.add(Constants.TODATE.getValue(), CommonUtils.formatDateddmmyyyy("12-12-2021", "yyyy-MM-dd"),Types.CHAR);
parameters.add("issuerid", "50191150159",Types.CHAR);
MapSqlParameterSource source = new MapSqlParameterSource(parameters);
```

I don't think this would change the content of the object though, I'd make sure that your `Constants.getValue()` outputs match the database side, and that the dates you are putting in are formatted properly (i notice you have the dates inputted as dd-mm-yyyy, but then have yyyy-MM-dd after them, so just in case you didn't notice that)